# Problem1 running Powershell command in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, powershell, windows-10

I want to run a PowerShell command from my vb.net program. The way I run command is:

```
Shell("powershell.exe Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register ""$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml""}", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, True)
```

The actual command is:

```
Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

When I copy above command and paste it in PowerShell, it works. However, when I run the same command using the code (Shell), some error occurs. PowerShell fills with red text. Before I can read anything, the window closes. I have checked the code and command several times. But still don't know why different results for same command.

Comment: Try adding `-NoExit` switch to powershell.exe - then you'll be able to see the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly how that command is getting interpreted could be causing problems.  You could try to fix it by being a bit more explicit in the command line by adding the `-command` switch and quoting your command.

```
Shell("powershell.exe -command ""Get-AppXPackage | ...""", ...)
```

As an example of this.  Try to run the following command from cmd.exe:

```
C:\>powershell dir c:\ | select Name
'select' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

But if you use `-command` then the problem goes away.

```
C:\>powershell -command "dir c:\ | select Name"

Name
----
Debug
etc.
```

This is obviously not the exact same behavior, but something similar could be causing the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried it but unfortunately still it's not working. The error is "a positional parameter cant be found that accepts argument '\AppxManifest.xml'

Comment: It sounds like something is getting messed up in the transition from VB.  Try to simplify your command by doing something like `Write-Host ""$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml""` for the command.  This will hopefully let you see what's actually being passed for that valueso you can determine if there's an extra quote or a quote missing.